# Size of Release and Debug builds

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I have project which was written on C/C++, build genearator is cmake, gcc version is 4.8.4, operation system is Linux, via ls -la i compare size of exe file and receive next values:

```
DEBUG => 10.386.834 bytes
RELEASE => 1.427.407 bytes
RELWITHDEBINFO => 16.660.386 bytes
MINSIZEREL => 1.017.342 bytes
```

And now i have question why RELWITHDEBINFO executable file bigger than in DEBUG mode?

Comment: Maybe this reasoning? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101487/release-mode-static-library-much-larger-than-debug-mode-version

Comment: Generating good debug info for an optimized build is harder.  Play with -fvar-tracking